# Series of squares of n integers - where is the mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following two series:

$$1^3 + 2^3 + ... + n^3$$
$$0^3 + 1^3 + .... + (n-1)^3$$

I take the difference vertically of the two:

$$\left(1^3-0^3\right) + \left(2^3-1^3\right) + .... + \left(n^3-(n-1)^3\right)$$

This equals to $n^3$

If I now express this in sum notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(i^3-(i-1)^3\right) = n^3$$

If I expand: $(i-1)^3 = i^3 - 3i^2 + 3i - 1$

Thus

$$\left(i^3 - (i-1)^3\right) = 3i^2 - 3i +1$$

My sum is now:

$$3\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 -3 \sum_{i=1}^n i + n = n^3$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2  = \frac{1}{3} \left(n^3 + 3 \frac{n(n-1)}{2}  -n\right)$$

And the expression on the RHS above is not $\frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (2n+1)$

I don't want to solve the above using forward difference, I want to keep it backward.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n\color{red}{+}1)}2$.

Comment: I came here expecting "[s]eries of squares".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i={n(n+1)\over2}\quad\text{ not }\quad {n(n-1)\over2}$$

Comment: Oh God... why was I thinking about maximum number of unique pairs...

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal, it's an easy mistake to make.  You gave a very clear presentation of your approach, which made it easy for fresh eyes to spot the error.

Comment: Thank  you very much for spotting it.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is when you evaluate
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
The correct formula is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
plugging this, everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac 12n(n{\color{red}+}1)$, hence
\begin{align*}
  \frac 13 \left(n^3 + 3\frac{n(n+1)}2 - n\right) 
   &= \frac 16 n(2n^2 + 3n + 3 - 2)\\
   &= \frac 16 n(2n^2 + 3n + 1)\\
   &= \frac 16 n(2n+1)(n+1)
\end{align*}